# How do I solve this following rpi-fbcp error?

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi-zero

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
~$ cd rpi-fbcp/
~/rpi-fbcp$ mkdir build
~/rpi-fbcp$ cd build/
~/rpi-fbcp/build$ cmake ..
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of code such as
    project(ProjectName)
  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
```

I am trying to git this https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp

I am following this tutorial
https://www.instructables.com/Connected-Round-Screen-240x240-GC9A01-Controller-t/#discuss

Comment: This is not an **error** but a **warning**. It doesn't prevent the project from being built. You could ignore it.

Comment: The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done
Generating done
Build files have been written to: /home/dietpi/rpi-fbcp/build

Comment: That is what happens when I build

Comment: Then this error:

dietpi@DietPi:~/rpi-fbcp/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target fbcp
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/fbcp.dir/main.c.o
/home/dietpi/rpi-fbcp/main.c:9:10: fatal error: bcm_host.h: No such file or directory
9 | #include <bcm_host.h>
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fbcp.dir/build.make:82: CMakeFiles/fbcp.dir/main.c.o] E rror 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/fbcp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2

Comment: Do not use comments for error messages. Instead, add them to the **question post** itself.

Comment: BTW, the error message about missed `bsm_host.h` is not a project-specific: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/fatal-error-bcm-host-h-no-such-file-or-directory-compilation-terminated